# Deploying node js application to aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

So I have develop a REST API based on `Node` and `Express`. It is based with node `v6.9`. I currently run in with pm2. I have trouble on which AWS service should I deploy to.

What are the steps and is there any aws specific npm library that i should install?

Comment: I believe this is easily researchable via a web search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using EC2 for deployment on AWS. I have summarised some steps to help you in getting started 
Steps:

5.You would be redirected to the above page choose an instance in which you are comfortable with like in my case I am comfortable with ubuntu so I choose Ubuntu server.

It will take you to your created Instance

1. Sign in into the AWS console.
2. Choose the EC2 from the AWS services console.
3. Choose Launch Instance.

   4.[image]

   5.You would be redirected to the above page choose an instance in which you are comfortable with like in my case I am comfortable with ubuntu so I choose Ubuntu server.

   6.After that you will have to choose an Instance type based on your consumption you can choose one according to the memory.

   7.[image]

   8.Click on review and launch 
   It will take you to the review page
   In which you have to select the launch button.

   9.It will ask you to create a key pair choose a new key pair 
   and download the new key pair.

   10.Click on launch Instance
   It will take you to your Instances dashboard where you can see your all your instances and their states

   11.Now open the terminal and change the permission of the key you downloaded previously "chmod 400 Your_key.pem"

   12.connect to your instance by using 
   "ssh -i "Your_key.pem" your "public DNS""

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a virtual server on AWS. In AWS ecosystem it is called as EC2. On that server you will have root access and then you can install anything on that server (node and other dependancies. You will need to pay for the server. Ot doesn't matter you call any API or not, you have to pay for the running server.

Alternatively, you can package your application and upload it on AWS lambda. This way you will not need to provision any server. You pay for only the calls you make to AWS lambda. If you do not make any call you don't pay anything. The first 1 million calls are free per month and the next calls are charged at 0.2 USD per million.